# JaxWS 2.0 - always returning Internal Server Error

Tags: web-services, jboss, websphere, weblogic, jax-ws

I have a JAX-WS 2.0 web service implementation. I know that due to security features jaxws always throw internal server error and my original error is suppressed. Is there any way to disable this feature for JaxWS 2.0.

I tried the following in websphere8.5.5.6 with no success webservices.unify.faults = false

I need a suitable setting in weblogic/websphere/jboss.

Comment: Are you getting soap faults as described here? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13734/faults.htm#WSADV630

Comment: Yes i am getting the soap fault but it gives only one response which is Internal Server Error.

Comment: Are you saying that the provider throwing the error is WebSphere and that setting webservices.unify.faults = false isn't working?  Or that you want the same kind of thing for another runtime?

Comment: Jax WS by default throws the error "Internal Server error!". In case of websphere 8.5.5 IBM given a work around to suppress using this setting which never worked for me. If I am right, this is going to be permanent impact.